# Why whould I want to disable .NET Code Contracts

Tags: c#, code-contracts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.net 4.0 Code Contracts. When to use? When are they a waste of time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111332/net-4-0-code-contracts-when-to-use-when-are-they-a-waste-of-time)

I started to read the full documentation of the .NET Code Contracts and I noticed that you can specify the compiler not to emit the code corresponding to your contracts. But I was wondering WHY someone would want to do that?! I mean, from the documentation, code contracts are about specifying pre / post / invariants about your code.

Looking at another question [.net 4.0 Code Contracts. When to use? When are they a waste of time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111332/net-4-0-code-contracts-when-to-use-when-are-they-a-waste-of-time), it seems that contracts should guard against invalid state of an object, but then again, why would I want to disable them! In doing so, wouldn't I open the door for a mountain of problems?

Should they be used as business validation, like making sure that a `startDate <= endDate` or should I use the good old if-then-throw for business? If I disable the code contracts my class could now be in an invalid state.

So my question remains, why would I want to disable code contracts?

Comment: It's on the list, that already gets our attention :-)  Asking why already emphasizes why...

Answer (score 1):

One scenario I can think of, if you have conditions that are expensive to test for, you may want to disable then in release builds, for performance gains.

Comment: is there a trade-off to be made between quality / stability and performance here? Since if you don't include these conditions, your object becomes open for invalid data, the second part of my question talk about if I should use these conditions in business validation.

Comment: You should not use Code Contracts for validation of user data. The exceptions thrown are not designed to be caught, as they are intended to indicate a serious defect in the code.

Answer (score 0):

For the same reason [`Debug.Assert()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kssw4w7z.aspx) is not compiled into the Release build. Sometimes you can detect a non-fatal invalid condition, and for some applications continuing execution is the desired behavior. Keeping code contract in the Release build is like using [`Trace.Assert()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk4kachs.aspx).

I personally always keep contracts, as I don't even try to plan my code to somehow survive being in an invalid state.

Comment: Then should you a condition that cannot be removed? I the case if a core business validation, shouldn't we use if-then-throw?

Comment: You could, or you could use the terser syntax of Code Contracts (and other added benefits).